# Spring Batch Step Integration Testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm looking for some general opinions and advice on testing a Spring batch step and step execution.

My basic step reads in from an api, processes into an entity object and then writes to a DB. I have tested the happy path, that the step completes successfully. What I now want to do is test the exception handling when data is missing at the processor stage. I could test the processor class in isolation, but I'd rather test the step as a whole to ensure the process failure is reflected correctly at step/job level.

I've read the spring batch testing guidelines and if I'm honest, I'm slightly lost within it. Is it possible to use **StepScopeTestUtils.doInStepScope** or updating the **StepExecution** to test this scenario? Ideally I'd force the reader to return faulty data before the processor kicks in.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach depends on the scope of your test. Reading a little between the lines here, I assume you are using a Spring IT, setting up a Spring context and using the JobLauncherTestUtils to start a job or a step.

I think the easiest way is replace one of your beans with a mock that triggers the error scenario. Using Mockito, this can be done by adding something like this to your test-configuration.

```
@Bean
public ReaderDataRepository dataApi(){
    return mock(ReaderDataRepository.class);
}
```

This bean then overrides the actual implementation. In the test setup you can then configure this mock very explicitly.

```
@Autowired
private ReaderDataRepository mockedRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(mockedRepository.getData()).thenReturn(faultyData())
}
```

This involves very little manipulation of Spring 'magic' and very explicitly defines the error from within the test.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answer makes perfect sense. Will accept and update with my own comment once I successfully implement.